# User Variable as value in Javascript name value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

I'm working with charts.js and using the doughnut chart. I'm passing a server side (coldfusion) variable to javascript, with hopes of using it in my chart.

```
var <cfoutput>#ToScript(pieAmount, "generated_key")#;</cfoutput>
var sharePiePolorDoughnutData = [
        {
            value: generated_key,
            color: "#455C73",
            highlight: "#34495E",
            label: "Dark Grey"
    },
        {
            value: 50,
            color: "#9B59B6",
            highlight: "#B370CF",
            label: "Purple Color"
    },
        {
            value: 150,
            color: "#BDC3C7",
            highlight: "#CFD4D8",
            label: "Gray Color"
    },
        {
            value: 180,
            color: "#26B99A",
            highlight: "#36CAAB",
            label: "Green Color"
    },
        {
            value: 100,
            color: "#3498DB",
            highlight: "#49A9EA",
            label: "Blue Color"
    }

];
```

When inspecting the element, the value of the name: value pair is just reading the javascript variable, not the value of the variable.

How do I get the value of the variable to be read in the data structure?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show what you mean by javascript variable and not the value, and inspect how?

Comment: What is the value of the variable you have now? Is it a string?

Comment: So I guess in `value: generated_key` you want *generated_key* to be the value assigned to the variable *generated_key*, not the string "generated_key"?

Comment: can you supply the rendered code? (the code, the browser received.)

Comment: I inspected with the chrome browser tools. The above code snippet is what I'm submitting to the browser. This line var <cfoutput>#ToScript(pieAmount, "generated_key")#;</cfoutput> declares a javascript variable called generated_key. When I view what was sent to the browser, it reads value: generated_key . If I do window.alert(generated_key), I get "114" which is what I'm looking for